# Why doesn't my program recognize the last names properly?

Tags: java

The scanner reads the wrong data, the text file format is:

```
111，Smith，Sam, 40，10.50
330，Jones，Jennifer，30，10.00
```

The program is:

```java
public class P3 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String file=args[0];
        File fileName = new File(file);
        try {
            Scanner sc = new Scanner(fileName).useDelimiter(", ");
            while (sc.hasNextLine()) {
                if (sc.hasNextInt( ) ){ int id = sc.nextInt();}
                String lastName = sc.next();
                String firstName = sc.next();  
                if (sc.hasNextInt( ) ){ int hours = sc.nextInt();   }
                if (sc.hasNextFloat()){ float payRate=sc.nextFloat();  }
                System.out.println(firstName);
            }
            sc.close();
        } catch(FileNotFoundException e) {  
            System.out.println("Can't open file "       
                               +   fileName + " ");
        }
    }
}
```

The output is:

```
40，10.50
330，Jones，Jennifer，30，10.00
```

It is supposed to be:

```
Sam
Jennifer
```

How do I fix it?

Comment: And what about Smith and Jones?

Comment: if is System.out.println(lastName);

Comment: it should print Smith and Jones

Comment: but why the lastName it's Smith and Jones?

Comment: The question INCLUDES " the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself", and has a very "clear problem statement". I don't think it would be offtopic.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that your data isn't just delimited by commas.  It is also delimited by line-endings, and also by [Unicode character U+FF0C](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/ff0c/index.htm) (FULLWIDTH COMMA).

I took your code, replaced the line

```
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(fileName).useDelimiter(", ");
```

with

```
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(fileName, "UTF-8").useDelimiter(", |\r\n|\n|\uff0c");
```

and then ran it.  It produced the output it was supposed to.

The text `, |\r\n|\n|\uff0c` is a regular expression that matches either:

- a comma followed by a space,
- a carriage-return (`\r`) followed by a newline (`\n`),
- a newline on its own,
- a Unicode full-width comma (`\uff0c`).

These are the characters we want to delimit the text by.  I've specified both types of line-ending as I'm not sure which line-endings your file uses.

I've also set the scanner to use the UTF-8 encoding when reading from the file.  I don't know whether that will make a difference for you, but on my system UTF-8 isn't the default encoding so I needed to specify it.

Answer (score 0):

First, please swap `fileName` and `file`. Next, I suggest you use a [`try-with-resources`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html). Your variables need to be at a common scope if you intend to use them. Finally, when using `hasNextLine()` I would then **call** `nextLine` and you can *`split`* on *optional* white space and comma. That could look something like

```
String fileName = // ...
File file = new File(fileName);
try (Scanner sc = new Scanner(file)) {
    while (sc.hasNextLine()) {
        String line = sc.nextLine();
        String[] arr = line.split("\\s*,\\s*");
        int id = Integer.parseInt(arr[0]);
        String lastName = arr[1];
        String firstName = arr[2];
        int hours = Integer.parseInt(arr[3]);
        float payRate = Float.parseFloat(arr[4]);
        System.out.println(firstName);
    }
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    System.out.println("Can't open file " + fileName + " ");
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: if we have to use Scanner(file).useDelimiter(", ") ,  how to fix it?